# Not able to find Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition. but can find Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis

Tags: windows-store-apps, speech-recognition

I am trying to add Speech recognition to a windows store app. I am developing this application using VS 2015.
I can not find Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition namespace to include in the project.
But can find Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.

Answer (score 0):

The windows store app targets windows 8.1 and not windows phone 8.1. Hence the reason for "Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition" not appearing.

As I added windows Phone 8.1 as target, I could add the name space "Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition"

But I did not yet understand why Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis is part of windows store app and not Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.

Here is a similar question --> https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6934ae6d-530f-4b21-9918-e8dfbc1231a0/visual-studio-wont-let-me-use-speech-recognition-in-a-universal-windows-app-based-on-the-band-sdk?forum=Offtopic